# Stop IEnumerable from enumerating through all elements

Tags: c#, ienumerable

How do I stop `IEnumberable` from enumerating through all the elements in the variable in question.
I have a function which I pass an `IEnumerable` list to, and it will always have only two elements. I however, need the function to only run for the first element, no more, no less. How do I get it to only go through the first element?

Note: Since there are only two elements, I've tried passing them in separately (e.g `double` `double`), but it still runs through both.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Why can't you use `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first item from the list? Or even `list[0]`?

Comment: Why are you even iterating over the enumerable?  If it always has two elements (how are you sure of that?) and you only want the first element, just target the first one...

Comment: Why not use Tuple instead of IEnumerable if the variable is always a collection with two items?

Comment: @yacoubMassad `public List<IdentifiedBoard> FindBoards(IEnumerable <SimpleProfile> profile)` ...thats whats being passed in.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34732032/edit) your question to include the details you provided in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) method to do something like this:

```
profile = profile.Take(1);
```

Now, when you enumerate `profile`, you will go through one item only.

Comment: Might be useful to use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` instead, so that you get `T` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` (even though it's guaranteed to have 0..1 items)

Comment: @Rob - `First` and `FirstOrDefault` do not return an `IEnumerable<T>`, they return an instance of the object.  The method expects an `IEnumerable<T>`  The OP could change the method to accept an instance of `T` and then do as you suggest.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That's exactly what I said, that you should use `First*` so that you get `T`, and *not* `IEnumerable<T>`. I would have assumed this could also be in the method that accepts `IEnumerable<T>` (if changing the declaration was impossible).

Comment: @Rob, you are right. I was giving a direct answer on how to "stop IEnumerable from enumerating through all elements" , and I think that the way to do that is to have an IEnumerable that goes through just one element via `Take(1)`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked:) ...I don't understand why the negative points though:/

Answer (score 0):

The following code displays:

> Returning 0

which confirms that only one of the items has actually been evaluated.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var numbers = GetNumbers(2);

    var result = numbers.Take(1);

    // Evaluate only first number
    result.ToArray();       
}

public static IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers(int max)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Returning {0}", i); 
        yield return i;
    }
}
```